# Change date format Java getting Unparseable date Error

Tags: java, datetime

I have a date in the following format:

```
lastUpdatedDate = "12/14/2021 09:15:17";
```

I used the following code/format to convert date into yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date lastUpdatedDateFormatted = dt.parse(lastUpdatedDate);
```

But it gives me below error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12/14/2021 09:15:17"
```

output should be: 2021-12-14 09:15:17

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have told SimpleDateFormat to expect `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` but you have not given it a string in that format.

Comment: A `java.util.Date` instance is not in any particular format, and your code will not have *any* output to the console. You need to convert the string to a date, using the format that the string is in, and then convert the date to a string using the format that you want.

Comment: You format doesn't match your input, so it's impossible to parse, but since it's 2021, you really should stop using the older, out-of-date, effectively deprecated classes, and start using the `java.time` API instead, for example: `LocalDate.parse("12/14/2021 09:15:17", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the format to

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date lastUpdatedDateFormatted = dt.parse(lastUpdatedDate);

System.out.println(lastUpdatedDateFormatted);
```

And it should be able to parse the date then.

Comment: These terrible classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting pattern fails to match your input string.

And you are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes.

Your input lacks an indicator of time zone or offset from UTC, so parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = 
    LocalDateTime
    .parse(
        "12/14/2021 09:15:17" ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss" ) ;
    ) ;
```

Your desired output is nearly compliant with the ISO 8601 standard format used by default in *java.time*, except for that SPACE in the middle rather than `T`.

```
String output = ldt.toString().replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

*As you are wanting to display or output the date in **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** format, you should parse the date first then format the date to desired format.*

```
try {
   String lastUpdatedDate = "12/14/2021 09:15:17";
   Date lastDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(lastUpdatedDate);
   System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(lastDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```